# How to combine np string array with float array python

Tags: python, arrays, string, floating-point, scientific-notation

I would like to combine an array full of floats with an array full of strings. Is there a way to do this?

(I am also having trouble rounding my floats, insert is changing them to scientific notation; I am unable to reproduce this with a small example)

```
A=np.array([[1/3,257/35],[3,4],[5,6]],dtype=float)
B=np.array([7,8,9],dtype=float)
C=np.insert(A,A.shape[1],B,axis=1)
print(np.arround(B,decimals=2))
D=np.array(['name1','name2','name3'])
```

How do I append D onto the end of C in the same way that I appended B onto A (insert D as the last column of C)?

I suspect that there is a type issue between having strings and floats in the same array. It would also answer my questions if there were a way to change a float (or maybe a scientific number, my numbers are displayed as '5.02512563e-02') to a string with about 4 digits (.0502).

I believe concatenate will not work, because  the array dimensions are (3,3) and (,3). D is a 1-D array, D.T is no different than D. Also, when I plug this in I get "ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions."

I don't care about accuracy loss due to appending, as this is the last step before I print.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dtype=object` in your numpy array; like bellow:

```
np.array([1, 'a'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making D a numpy array first, then transposing and concatenating with C:

```
D=np.array([['name1','name2','name3']])
np.concatenate((C, D.T), axis=1)
```

See the documentation for concatenate for explanation and examples:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

Comment: As D is a 1-D array, D.T is no different than D.

Comment: I'm confused.  How can D be a one D array and be added onto C?  Can you show what the expected final output is?

Answer (score 0):

numpy arrays support only one type of data in the array. Changing the float to str is not a good idea as it will only result in values very close to the original value.

Try using pandas, it support multiple data types in single column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np_ar1 = np.array([1.3, 1.4, 1.5])
np_ar2 = np.array(['name1', 'name2', 'name3'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ar1':np_ar1})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ar2':np_ar2})
pd.concat([df1.ar1, df2.ar2], axis=0)
```