# Multiplying A Matrix By A String

Tags: arrays, string, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I am trying to multiply a matrix by constants I have defined as the following:

```
E1 = "E1"
E2 = "E2"
J = "J"
```

However then when I try to multiply them by the matrices defined below I end up with an error:

```
# Defining the sigma functions and Identity matrices:
sigx = np.array([[0,1],[1,0]])
sigy = np.array([[0,-1j],[1j,0]])
sigz = np.array([[1,0],[0,-1]])
I1 = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
I2 = I1
```

[image]

```
# Trying to structure a Hamiltonian
H1 = np.kron(((E1)*(sigz)),I2)
H2 = np.kron((E2*(I1)),(sigz))
H3 = J*((np.kron((sigx),(sigx)))+(np.kron((sigy),(sigy))))
print(H1)
print(H2)
print(H3)
# Overall Hamiltonian Matrix 
Hs = H1 + H2 + H3
print(Hs)
```

[image]

The script works if I do not define E1, E2 or J beforehand as shown above but it only works because python automatically assigns them a value of 1,2,3. How can I get it so E1,E2 and J appear in the matrix operation outputs?

Comment: Numpy can't do symbolic math, which is what it looks like you're trying to do.  If you're trying to do something that requires symbolic math, you can use sympy instead.  Otherwise, if you know the value of `J` in terms of numbers, you should set the variable `J` to that instead of a string.

Comment: What exactly is this calculation supposed to accomplish (i.e. what are you trying to do with the hamiltonian once you define it)?

Comment: Ok I'll try rewrite it with sympy. Does that library have the same packages as numpy like kron?

Comment: I am trying to get the Hamiltonian and from there I can get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Comment: You want the eigenvalues and eigenstates for specific values of E1, E2, and J, or you want a symbolic expression for the eigenvalues and eigenstates of the hamiltonian in terms of those variables?

Comment: The second way you said it. Apologies for not being more clear

Comment: No problem.  In that case you want a symbolic math package (if you're sticking with python, that'd be sympy).  Sympy actually has a quantum mechanics package, although I've never used the quantum mechanics package and I'm not sure what's in there

Comment: Perfect I'll look into it thanks a mil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started here is your code translated to sympy:

```
import sympy as sp

I1 = I2 = sp.eye(2)

# Pauli matrices
# (there is sympy.physics.paulialgebra but I do not know how to use it)
sigx = sp.Matrix([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
sigz = sp.diag(1, -1)
sigy = sigx * sigz * sp.I

# symbolic constants
E1, E2, J = sp.symbols('E1 E2 J')

kp = sp.kronecker_product

H1 = kp(E1 * sigz, I2)
H2 = kp(E2 * I1, sigz)
H3 = J * (kp(sigx, sigx) + kp(sigy, sigy))

Hs = H1 + H2 + H3

# now we can for example compute eigen decomposition
evals, mults, evecs = zip(*Hs.eigenvects())
```

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful

Answer (score 2):

First time posting here.

I hope I'm not stating the obvious, but **it looks like you are multiplying a matrix of integers by strings. I think you have to define the constants as integers *(or doubles or floats possibly)***. You are doing matrix multiplication using the Kronecker product but you are multiplying integers by strings causing the dtype(U11) error.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Here you can see that the 'U11' error means an little-Endian 11 Character Unicode String.

Comment: That's fair I get that man but I'm trying to understand how else to go about it if that's the case. Appreciate the input

Comment: You might find this useful.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958506/element-wise-string-concatenation-in-numpy

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468188/how-to-combine-np-string-array-with-float-array-python

These might point you in a direction you could go. They are about concatenating string arrays. 

You could also try MATLAB.